# Edit position of a circle that contains a text

Tags: html, css

I was trying to add some texts inside a badge (a circle). It went well creating the circle but the problem is that I want to align my circle with my text.

[image: Initial state]

As you can see here , The start of the circle is at the same level as my text, I want to center it so the 100% would be on same level with the previous text `[FETCH NOM CERTIF]`

```css
.badge {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 100%;
  /* may require vendor prefixes */
  background: #3dd16e;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.inline {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<img class="icon" src="../../../media/img/skills.png">
<h4 class="headLines">Compétences :</h4><br>
<h6 class="paddtext inline">Certificat : [FETCH NOM CERTIF] <span class="badge">100%</span></h6><br>
<h6 class="paddtext inline">Certificat : [FETCH NOM CERTIF] <span class="badge">95%</span></h6><br>
<h6 class="paddtext inline">Certificat : [FETCH NOM CERTIF] <span class="badge">90%</span></h6><br>
<h6 class="paddtext inline">Certificat : [FETCH NOM CERTIF] <span class="badge">85%</span></h6><br>
```

Comment: Re: vendor prefixes (not needed)... https://caniuse.com

Answer (score 1):

So for your example I just changed your centering strategy to `inline-flex` to act as an `inline` element as `span` is by default but which was changed with the `display: table-cell` to remain compliant. See below. Cheers.

```css
.badge {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 100%;
  /* may require vendor prefixes */
  background: #3dd16e;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.inline {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<img class="icon" src="../../../media/img/skills.png">
<h4 class="headLines">Compétences :</h4><br>
<h6 class="paddtext inline">Certificat : [FETCH NOM CERTIF] <span class="badge">100%</span></h6><br>
<h6 class="paddtext inline">Certificat : [FETCH NOM CERTIF] <span class="badge">95%</span></h6><br>
<h6 class="paddtext inline">Certificat : [FETCH NOM CERTIF] <span class="badge">90%</span></h6><br>
<h6 class="paddtext inline">Certificat : [FETCH NOM CERTIF] <span class="badge">85%</span></h6><br>
```

Comment: I just added some padding and it's great. Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

You could try applying flex to the paddtext class

```
.paddtext {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you don't like how it looks when using `inline-flex` (other solutions) you can always use `transform` with `translate` and ajust the height on your own way:

```css
.badge {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 100%; /* may require vendor prefixes */
  background: #3dd16e;
  font-size: 10px;
  transform: translate(0,30%);

}

.inline{
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<img class="icon" src="../../../media/img/skills.png"><h4 class="headLines">
Compétences :</h4><br>
<h6 class="paddtext inline">Certificat : [FETCH NOM CERTIF] <span class="badge">100%</span></h6><br>
<h6 class="paddtext inline">Certificat : [FETCH NOM CERTIF] <span class="badge">95%</span></h6><br>
<h6 class="paddtext inline">Certificat : [FETCH NOM CERTIF] <span class="badge">90%</span></h6><br>
<h6 class="paddtext inline">Certificat : [FETCH NOM CERTIF] <span class="badge">85%</span></h6><br>
```